# PHPMyAdmin/setup show blank screen, while PMA itself works

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin

I'm setting up PHPMyAdmin on an NginX server. The system itself works, however, the /setup page where I should be able to change settings (i.e. build a new config.inc.php) is blank. It doesn't show an error, returns a 200 OK and there's nothing in /var/log/nginx/error.log.

Here's my nginx configuration for this server block:

```
listen [::]:80;

root                /usr/share/phpmyadmin; # path to my pma installation
index               index.php;
charset             utf-8;

server_name         my-host;

location / {
    autoindex       off;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files       $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\. {
    deny            all;
}

location /libraries {
    deny            all;
}

location /setup/lib {
    deny            all;
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

There seems to be an error in the /setup/lib/common.inc.php file:

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * Loads libraries/common.inc.php and preforms some additional actions
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin-setup
 */

/**
 * Do not include full common.
 * @ignore
 */
echo 1;
define('PMA_MINIMUM_COMMON', true);
define('PMA_SETUP', true);
chdir('..');
echo 2;
if (!file_exists('./libraries/common.inc.php')) {
    die('Bad invocation!');
}

echo 3;
require_once './libraries/common.inc.php';
require_once './libraries/config/config_functions.lib.php';
require_once './libraries/config/messages.inc.php';
require_once './libraries/config/ConfigFile.class.php';
require_once './libraries/url_generating.lib.php';
require_once './libraries/user_preferences.lib.php';
echo 4;

// use default error handler
restore_error_handler();

echo 5;

// Save current language in a cookie, required since we use PMA_MINIMUM_COMMON
$GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->setCookie('pma_lang', $GLOBALS['lang']);

echo 6;

ConfigFile::getInstance()->setPersistKeys(array(
    'DefaultLang',
    'ServerDefault',
    'UploadDir',
    'SaveDir',
    'Servers/1/verbose',
    'Servers/1/host',
    'Servers/1/port',
    'Servers/1/socket',
    'Servers/1/extension',
    'Servers/1/connect_type',
    'Servers/1/auth_type',
    'Servers/1/user',
    'Servers/1/password'));

echo 7;

// allows for redirection even after sending some data
ob_start();
```

Output: `123456`

Comment: I suggest looking in the php error log, white screens usually mean the php script died somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I'm using php-fastcgi, errors are passed to nginx and would appear in the nginx log.

Comment: I know, but sometimes it doesn't, I've faced stuff like this many times before, wouldn't hurt tailing the php error log and try refresh phpmyadmin.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady there is no PHP error log, because it passes everything to nginx.

Comment: what about editing `setup/index.php` and make the first line something like `die("working");` and see if it works, to understand if its nginx or php, if it works turn on error reporting and remove the die and run it again

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady good idea - that works! However it fails when I put the die after the first line, `require './lib/common.inc.php'`.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady okay, I debugged something more and added the results to my question. Could you take a look?

Comment: Add this on the top of the file `ini_set("display_errors","on")` see if it shows an error message

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady thanks, but I have that in my php.ini already :)

Comment: I am running into the same issue right now. I have narrowed down the error to /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/config/ConfigFile.class.php where the constructor loads CONFIG_FILE. That is where it craches without an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is same issue as [bug #1175142](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpmyadmin/+bug/1175142) , which has been fixed 4:4.0.1-2. The problem is that in Debian packaged phpMyAdmin, the config script includes one helper function, what prevented in config file being loaded multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it by changing the default buffer sizes in the nginx conf specific to my phpmyadmin directory.  The 4 last lines are the ones I add/changed.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
  fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
  fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
  fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed adding these options in my /etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf file:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
....
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
  fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
  fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
  fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
...
}
```

and restarting nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this. In case you

- Have a fresh install of `nginx`, `php7.4-fpm`, and perhaps MariaDB
- Properly configured `sites-enabled/` to run PHP and have a working `phpinfo()`
- Properly configured SSL even
- Downloaded `phpMyAdmin` as a zip, and extracted it

and yet it still returns a blank HTTP 200 page, did you remember to install its PHP dependencies? It turns out I completely forgot about its [requirements](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/require.html), such as `php-gd`.

To save time, I ran `apt-get install phpmyadmin`. It should pull everything phpMyAdmin needs to run properly. It should also set up its needed database structures.

Removing the `phpmyadmin` apt package afterward is optional, and I did since I download the zip from phpMyAdmin's site anyways.